# Error when mounting more than one truecrypt

Tags: ubuntu-10.04, truecrypt

I'm trying to mount two truecrypt volume. After I mounted the first one I can't mount the second one. If I unmount the first one than I can mount the second one. I'm getting the following error:

```
Error: device-mapper: create ioctl failed: Device or resource busy
```

**Updated**

Here is my two tests:

```
sudo truecrypt -t -p password --fs-options="users,uid=$(id -u mysql),gid=$(id -g
mysql),fmask=0027,dmask=0027" --mount /media/WESYS_DATA/test3 
/media/mysqltruecrypt/test2 --non-interactive

sudo truecrypt -t -p password --fs-options="users,uid=$(id -u mysql),gid=$(id -g
mysql),fmask=0027,dmask=0027" -k /keyfile/location 
--mount /media/WESYS_DATA/test2 /media/mysqltruecrypt/test --non-interactive
```

Answer (score 0):

You're probably using the same device name for the second device, you should post the commands that you used.